# IntelliIdea - Cannot see scala in add framework support

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I want to run scala code in IntelliJ Idea.
I donot see option scala in Add Framework Support

[image]

Please suggest how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To run the Scala code there is no need to add any framework or facet (things like this were done in some previous IntelliJ versions, but this is long ago).

The only thing you need is to install a Scala plugin.

If you did not install the plugin when installing the IDE, use menu item Settings, click on Plugin, then Marketplace and type Scala.

With a Scala plugin installed, you can create a new Scala project.

[image]

Comment: I am already using Scala Plugin.But I do not see option to create scala class. Picture attached in questions

Comment: Sometimes this happens to me with a freshly created project, most often pressing the refresh icon in the sbt tool windows helps. Other than that, what I see from the project looks fine to me.

Comment: Hi Suma, I have create a maven project and not a sbt project. I tried refreshing maven but this problem is still not resolved.

Comment: I am afraid Maven projects do not support Scala. You need to use SBT. There may exist some Maven plugin for Scala handling, but I have no experience with that.